# Memory errors when trying to create and populate a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsmutabledictionary

I am not a Cocoa developer, but I have been dabbling in it to build some plugins for PhoneGap. This particular plugin method is either 1) crashing the app without saying why or 2) complaining about how I release/don't release an object. I have tried a ton of things on my end, including using an Enumerator instead of the for loop. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome. I don't mind legwork:

```
- (void)getPreferences:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];
    NSString* jsCallback = nil;

    if (argc > 0) {
        jsCallback = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Preferences.getPreferences: Missing 1st parameter.");
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
    NSMutableArray *keys = (NSMutableArray *) [options objectForKey:@"keys"];
    NSMutableDictionary *values = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSUInteger ky = [keys count];
    for (int i = 0; i < ky; i ++) {
        @try {

            [values  setObject:[defaults objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        @catch (NSException * err) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", err);
        }
    }

    [keys release];

    NSString* jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", jsCallback, [values JSONRepresentation]];

    [defaults release];
    [values release];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    [jsString release];
}
```

Human version:

1. `options` contains a dictionary with a single key of "keys"
2. that key contains an array of strings (that are going to be used as keys for lookup)
3. I want to loop through that array *and*
4. For every value that exists in `defaults` for that key, copy it to `values` using the same key
5. Finally, I want to send that `values` back as JSON (This part was working when I just passed the entire `defaults` object in, so I think the JSON method is working)

Comment: sorry to bother you with something totally off-topic, but do you happen to have news on the downloadify site? Is there a mirror somewhere? I have a number of posts where I point to it, and edited them to link to your github profile instead. Is that the best location at the moment?

Comment: @Pekka, yes, for the moment. The new home will probably be at labs.dougneiner.com/downloadify. I feel like an idiot for not renewing the name... by the time I did, it was a few days too late. #fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it follows that you 'own' objects `values` and `jsString` (the ones you created with `alloc`), so you should release them and not any other.
You can read more on memory management [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Is this the whole code? Also, what exactly error do you get?

Comment: +1 Wow, removing the other two release calls fixed it. Also, the concept of owning it made sense to me. Thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: @Doug The link I added should help with understanding general concepts: it's short, but clear. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Nikita is right, it looks as though you're overreleasing `defaults`, which would cause a crash later when the autorelease pool gets released. Also, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you could create the `values` dictionary with a single line of code:

```
NSDictionary *values = [defaultsDict dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I wanted. Wow, that was way easier than I thought. Thank you! +1